# How to place responsively sizing text over images without breaking grid structure?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I created a responsive grid of 12 equal images (400px x 400px) on the basis of Bootstrap 3 and added a heading h2 with span over each image, which should only appear when hovering over the tile.

The problem is that on smaller screensizes (width smaller than 990px) the text is not responsively changing its size in line with the images and is breaking out of the grid structure. I created a JS Bin for demonstration purposes:

**http://jsbin.com/OdAfUqE/2/**

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate your help on this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="service-wrapper">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding" >

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

</div>


<div class="row" id="service-wrapper">

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding" >

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">

        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">

            <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></h2>

            <div><img src="../img/service12.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nopadding {
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
}

.row {
margin: 0;
}

#service-wrapper img {
width: 100%;
}

#service-wrapper {
position: relative;
/*display: block;*/
}

#service-wrapper h2 {
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
line-height: 1.2;

position: absolute;

font-weight: 400;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #0066FF;
color: #000;
padding: 0;
margin-top:0px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

-webkit-transition: opacity .2s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s linear;
-o-transition: opacity .2s linear;
transition: opacity .2s linear;    
}

service-wrapper h2 span {
display: block;

padding: 10px;

color: white; 
font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
letter-spacing: -1px;  
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);    
}

#service-wrapper a:hover h2 {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the font-size use media queries: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/. Set some break-points (320, 480, 540, 768, or whatever you want) and lower the font-size with each of these.
Also, use the em unit on font-size, and reset the line-height to normal.

Comment: Another viable option for this would be using `vw` units to scale the font based on the width of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the font-sizes and/or padding with media queries?